# Undeclared identifier "ComponentState" under CollectionItem

Tags: delphi, collections, components

Why `ComponentState` from the bellow code it's not recognized by Delphi under a `CollectionItem` class.

Remark: Under `TMyComp` methods is working.

```
uses
  System.Classes, ...

type
  TMyComp = class(TComponent)
  ...

  TColumnsItem = class(TCollectionItem)
  private
    FWidth: Integer;
    procedure SetWidth(const Value: Integer);
  protected
    function GetDisplayName: String; override;
    procedure SetIndex(Value: Integer);  override;
  public
    constructor Create(Collection: TCollection); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Assign(Source: TPersistent); override;
  published
    property Width: Integer read FWidth write SetWidth default 90;
  end;


  procedure TColumnsItem.SetWidth(const Value: Integer);
  begin
  if FWidth <> Value then
    begin
      FWidth:= Value;
      if csDesigning in ComponentState then //Undeclared identifier 'ComponentState' ???
        begin
          //do something...
        end;
      Changed(False);
    end;
  end;
```

Comment: Observe the ascendant in [docs](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TCollectionItem).

Comment: wow! and how can i do it otherwise?

Comment: Ok, I found the answer! I should use the owner, like this example: `if not (csLoading in Owner.Header.Treeview.ComponentState)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ComponentState` is a property under `TComponent`.

To be used under `TCollectionItem` is necessary to define a `FOwner` property to the `TComponent`and to be used like:

```
if csDesigning in FOwner.ComponentState then
  begin
    //do something...
  end;
```